# When does the overdrive meter go up or down with a certain action?

Tags: chained-echoes

A central part of the combat system in Chained Echoes is the overdrive meter. It will determine how much tech points each move costs and how much damage the team can deal and be dealt. You want to keep it in the green "overdrive" zone and avoid the red "overheat" zone:

[image: overdrive meter in chained echoes]

Each action (attack, defend, skills, switch character,...) makes the meter goes up or down. The same action can fill the meter in one round and drain it in another.

Is there systematology whether the meter goes up or down with a certain action? I want to plan rounds ahead and this kind of information would make it easier to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching, Defending, and Ultra moves move the gauge to the left. Additionally, while in Overdrive or Overheat, the attack type icon shown on the left side also moves the gauge left. This is the only thing that changes. The number of actions until it changes is listed over the icon. All other actions and attack types move the gauge to the right.

I can't take screenshots, or I would make my own source, but there is a copy of the game's tutorials [here](https://www.naguide.com/chained-echoes-transcribed-tooltips/)